# How is the idea of "X comes a distant third" commonly expressed in Russian?

Tags: выражения, английский, german

We were having a conversation in German. Citing, one by one, three reasons why I think my friend has been hired for a job, I said jokingly:

> Die Antwort ist denkbar einfach. Erstens X. Zweitens Y. Dein Liebreiz **rangiert abgeschlagen auf Platz Drei**.

Or, as is more commonly phrased:

> Dein Liebreiz (**weit**) **abgeschlagen auf dem dritten Platz liegt**/**landet**.

In English, this is where we say:

> First, X. Second, Y. And your charm **comes a distant third** {/ comes in a distant third place}. The answer is as simple as that!

Answer (score 3):

It's `с большим отставанием`, like in phrase:

> На третьем месте с большим отставанием идёт Джон Макинрой.

or

> На втором месте с большим отставанием оказался фильм канала "Россия".

As a sidenote, the opposite of that is `с большим отрывом`.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly full equivalent but one can also say **и уже в самую последнюю очередь** without indication of the place number.

> Сначала А, потом Б, и уже в самую последнюю очередь В
>
> Во-первых А, во-вторых Б, и уже в самую последнюю очередь В

Answer (score 0):

It's *с большим отрывом*.

> Во-первых, А. Во-вторых, Б. Ну и в-третьих, с большим отрывом, твоё обаяние. Всё просто!

Comment: я бы сказал, что с большим отрывом - это ровно наоборот, обычно о лидирующем говорят, что он идёт с большим отрывом, а о проигрывающем - с большим отставанием.